# In jplayer how to use single playlist by two different player

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

My requirement is to use single playlist by two different player, one player is circle player and other player is simple jvideo player.

We have one xml file in which approx 20 songs url present, which will added to the jplayer playlist at the time when page loaded. This playlist is used by circle player. 
This is working fine, now my work is to add jvideo player which will use the same playlist of circle one on the basis of song type. Means if song is audio then it is run by circle player if it is video then by jvideo player.

To achieve this I am following steps:

1. First I check extension of song url if it is video then run by jvideo player
2. If it is audio then run by circle player.

The problem is audio is working fine but video player is playing then song is not changing automatically after finishing of present song, second time if I tried to run any video song then it not playing automatically, We have to press the play button manually.

To achieve this is I have to implement two different playlist or there is any other way, please suggest me any path I am trying hard but not getting any solution. I am not quite good in jquery but now I am better than before.

Comment: Does it really have to be the circle player for audio? I think, the requirement audio & video in one player is pretty close to this demo: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-media/

Comment: yup I already know that same player for both but my requirement is described above, please suggest me some method by which we can achieve my aim.